# Implementing a softmax attention pooling in a graph neural network

Tags: graph, pytorch, pytorch-geometric

I want to perform a softmax attention pooling of node features in a graph (I'm using `torch_geometric`. Given that I have my final node features `x` of shape `(146, 256)` what i do is first projecting them using a linear layer in order to have 1D scores:

```
scores
tensor([-0.0433, -0.0433, -0.0433, -0.0434, -0.0433, -0.0433, -0.0433, -0.0434,
        -0.0436, -0.0435, -0.0431, -0.0432, -0.0431, -0.0430, -0.0431, -0.0433,
        -0.0432, -0.0433, -0.0433, -0.0431, -0.0430, -0.0431, -0.0431, -0.0432,
        -0.0434, -0.0433, -0.0433, -0.0433, -0.0434, -0.0430, -0.0431, -0.0430,
        -0.0431, -0.0434, -0.0435, -0.0434, -0.0435, -0.0434, -0.0432, -0.0434,
        -0.0435, -0.0436, -0.0433, -0.0433, -0.0432, -0.0433, -0.0436, -0.0434,
        -0.0435, -0.0430, -0.0431, -0.0430, -0.0429, -0.0434, -0.0432, -0.0431,
        -0.0432, -0.0433, -0.0433, -0.0432, -0.0431, -0.0432, -0.0431, -0.0431,
        -0.0430, -0.0432, -0.0432, -0.0433, -0.0434, -0.0433, -0.0434, -0.0433,
        -0.0434, -0.0434, -0.0434, -0.0435, -0.0436, -0.0429, -0.0430, -0.0429,
        -0.0429, -0.0430, -0.0435, -0.0434, -0.0434, -0.0435, -0.0434, -0.0435,
        -0.0434, -0.0432, -0.0434, -0.0434, -0.0434, -0.0433, -0.0435, -0.0432,
        -0.0433, -0.0431, -0.0432, -0.0430, -0.0429, -0.0431, -0.0430, -0.0428,
        -0.0429, -0.0429, -0.0433, -0.0431, -0.0433, -0.0433, -0.0433, -0.0431,
        -0.0430, -0.0431, -0.0431, -0.0429, -0.0433, -0.0433, -0.0432, -0.0431,
        -0.0431, -0.0431, -0.0431, -0.0435, -0.0434, -0.0434, -0.0435, -0.0433,
        -0.0433, -0.0431, -0.0433, -0.0431, -0.0433, -0.0433, -0.0433, -0.0432,
        -0.0430, -0.0433, -0.0431, -0.0432, -0.0432, -0.0432, -0.0431, -0.0432,
        -0.0432, -0.0432], device='cuda:0')
```

Then, using the `batch` tensor, which tells you how many nodes you have in each graph,

```
tensor([ 0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  4,  4,  4,
         4,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  7,  7,  7,  7,  8,  8,  8,
         9,  9,  9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14,
        14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 18,
        18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 23, 23,
        23, 24, 24, 24, 24, 25, 25, 25, 26, 26, 26, 26, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28,
        28, 28, 28, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 30, 30, 30, 31, 31, 31, 31, 32, 32, 32,
        32, 33, 33, 33, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 35, 35, 35, 36, 36, 36, 36, 37, 37,
        37, 37], device='cuda:0')
```

I want to compute a softmax function `exp(x_i)/sum(exp(x_j))` in a way that for each graph `j` will only range through the number of nodes in that graph. I'm trying to use `torch_scatter` for this but not sure about how to achieve the result.
I have tried with `scatter_sum(torch.exp(scores)/torch.sum(torch.exp(scores)))` but I don't think it is the right solution.